# Returning structs and further clean up

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna

We're building a C++ library which is used within multiple contexts, Java/Kotlin being one of them. We're using JNI very extensively, but recently we thought that there's a lot of boilerplate around it and thought JNA might be a better idea. It is really nice for Java callbacks being called by the native code - the life-span of objects is not an issue then. We've hit a wall when trying to implement what I assumed was the "nominal" case. Let's assume we've got the following C++ struct to be returned "by value" by a native function and consumed in Java:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyCustomStruct {
  int x;
  std::vector<std::string> lines;
};
```

JNA needs C linkage and does not understand C++, so I adjusted the structure accordingly. Additionally, we cannot naively copy pointers when returning a struct, but rather deep copy the strings, because as soon as the stack unwinds, we're gonna loose our strings:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

extern "C" {
struct MyCustomStruct {
  int x;
  char** lines;
  int linesCount;
};

MyCustomStruct getMyCustomStructInstance() {
  std::vector<std::string> lines{"abc", "xyz"};
  MyCustomStruct result;

  result.lines = (char**)malloc(lines.size());
  for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    result.lines[i] = strdup(s.c_str());
  }
  
  result.x = 123;
  result.linesCount = lines.size();
  return result;
}
}
```

And the corresponding Java code:

```java
package my.native.package;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

public interface MyNativeCLibrary extends Library {
  public MyCustomStruct getMyCustomStructInstance();

  public static class MyCustomStruct extends Structure {
    public static class ByValue extends MyCustomStruct implements Structure.ByValue {}

    public int x;
    public PointerByReference lines;
    public int linesCount;

    public String[] linesAsArray() {
      return lines.getPointer().getStringArray(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
      return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "x", "lines", "linesCount" });
    }
  }
}
```

Now, on the caller side, I need to store that collection of strings (as in: it's a static variable kept in memory for the whole Java application's lifetime), so it'd be smart to deep copy it as well. Copying this `PointerByReference` sounds terrible, but is do-able for a person used to C++ and dealing with raw bytes. I'm going to have a hard time explaining the usage to my  client, but, well, I remotely imagine it.

Now, to the point: we've allocated some memory via `strdup`, now it'd make sense to clean it up (considering we've got a deep copy on Java end already). Following [eshayne's examples](https://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=11) I've added the cleanup method. In the end, the usage looks like this:

```java
MyCustomStruct foo = myLibraryHandle.getMyCustomStructInstance();
Application.foo = deepCopyMyCustomStruct(foo);
myLibraryHandle.cleanUpMyCustomStruct(foo);
```

That looks horrible, though. Even though we've got a Java wrapper on top of the JNA class which abstracts all those technical details away, I cannot figure out an "atomic" way of exposing such functions.

Is there any better mechanism for that? I feel there must be a more natural way of doing this.

I thought of wrapping such "unsafe" calls with some kind of a lambda:

```
myLibraryHandle.unsafeContext(() -> { myLibraryHandle.getMyCustomStructInstance(); }
```

but if the `unsafeContext` would accept any void function, there's no meta-way of knowing which functions have been called inside.

I also tried calling "cleanup" immediately after the native function (kinda hoping that JNA would deep copy...), but failed miserably.

Comment: Instead of managing memory manually, try to use Java's PhantomReference and a ReferenceQueue to automatically clean up the native memory when the Java object is garbage collected. This way, you don't need to worry about calling the cleanup method manually.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do. As far as I know, when transitioning between Java and native, JNA will do the necessary copying for you. There is generally no need to do this yourself. The same goes for cleanup. This too is generally handled by JNA (again, as far as I know). As far as I can tell you seem to have a bit of an X-Y problem, where you're now presenting a solution that is causing a problem, instead of giving us the original problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can't you instead create a Java class for MyCustomStruct, and then manually set its fields in a JNI function?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm simply trying to return an auto instance of a structure which contains a collection of strings inside and safely consume (i.e. cache globally) it by Java. Just thinking: how could JNA do a cleanup of natively allocated memory automatically, it does not know whether it's still referenced there, right? It's not that I'm passing the ownership here, just a raw pointer :(

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for that. Yeah JNI would work just fine (with a nasty boilerplate tho), just wanted to stick to JNA

Answer (score 0):

If you can use strdup, that implies your strings have no zero-bytes in them.

If your strings have no zero-bytes in them, you can replace the `char**` with a `char*` and a single large allocation with a zero-byte between each string and a `size_t` in the struct to indicate the length [1]. This makes the implementation *slightly* more clunky at both ends but (1) easier to conceptually understand, (2) more cache efficient, (3) easier to clean up, as all the deallocations can be replaced with a single call to `free` on your `char*`

[1] you might naively use two sequential zero-bytes to indicate the end of the string, but that would prevent you from having empty strings

```
extern "C"
{
    struct MyCustomStruct
    {
        char *text;
        size_t textLength;
    };

    MyCustomStruct getMyCustomStructInstance()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> lines{"abc", "xyz"};

        size_t textLength = 0;

        for (auto const &line : lines)
        {
            textLength += line.size()+1;
                        // the +1 is a magic constant here that indicates the
                        // presence of the null-byte at the end of each string
                        // you may want to do it differently so it doesn't
                        // just hang out here to confuse future readers
                        //  - A comment is possible, of course, but perhaps
                        //  not the best approach.
        }

        if (textLength == 0)
        {
            // some of these C functions don't handle edge cases
            // with zero-allocations so we're out immediately
            return MyCustomStruct{nulltpr, 0};
        }

        char *text = (char *)malloc(textLength);

        if (!text)
        {
            // insert your favorite error handling. For preference,
            // I would change the return type to
            // std::optional<MyCustomStruct> and do "return {};"
            // but you could also throw an exception here.
        }

        // At this point, the solution diverse, depending on how
        // performance sensitive you are. If you can accept two buffers
        //  (which I think you can, given the many strdup's you were
        //  willing to accept) I would do this:

        {
            std::string all_strings;
            all_strings.reserve(textLength);
            for (auto const &line : lines)
            {
                all_strings += line;
                all_strings += "\0";
            }
            std::copy(all_strings.begin(), all_strings.end(), text);

            return MyCustomStruct{text, textLength};
        }

        // If you are very performance sensitive here, I would instead:
        {
            auto next_string = text;

            for (auto const &line : lines)
            {
                std::copy(line.begin(), line.end, next_string);
                *next_string = '\0';
                ++next_string;
            }

            return MyCustomStruct{text, textLength};
        }
    }
}
```

NB: Obviously if you throw from this, or return a `std::optional`, you are no longer a good C function. I would probably make a pure C++ function for the logic, and then a pure C function that calls the C++ function and handles whatever error it might return in C parlance, e.g. like this:

```
MyCustomStruct myCustomStruct;
int result = fillMyCustomStruct(&myCustomStruct);
if(result != FillResult_Ok)
    //etc.
```

Comment: I mean, I'm not trying to optimise anything here, just merely trying to nicely consume a structure with a collection of strings inside